# Large JDF / PDF Print Job Rejected on Canon Vario 6000

Tags: pdf, printing, jdf

Using JDF Template to fill in data about my print job, which is then prepended to the pdf I am printing.

The print job transfers (via lpr) and prints successfully when there are not a lot of pages, but when I create a large job (1500 pages) it fails with a single page containing the error message: "Pdf conversion error: Expected a name object."

The template is mostly the same with the job name and a few other changes. But the media selection uses the RunIndex which runs up the page count making it a really large element. I am suspicious that I am hitting a limitation on the JDF processor.

This xml works:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<JDF ID="jdf_1" Type="Combined" Category="DigitalPrinting" Types="LayoutPreparation Imposition Interpreting Rendering DigitalPrinting HoleMaking Folding Stitching" Activation="Active" Status="Waiting" Version="1.3" xmlns="http://www.CIP4.org/JDFSchema_1_1" xmlns:oce="http://www.oce.com/JDF_Extension/1_00" DescriptiveName="test tiny batch">
  <Comment Name="oce:TicketVersion">4.00</Comment>
  <ResourcePool>
    <CustomerInfo ID="info_1" Class="Parameter" Status="Available" CustomerJobName="test tiny batch">
      <ContactRef rRef="contact_1" />
    </CustomerInfo>
    <RunList ID="runlist_id" Class="Parameter" Status="Available">
      <LayoutElementRef rRef="file_1" />
    </RunList>
    <LayoutElement ID="file_1" Class="Parameter" Status="Available">
      <FileSpec URL="cid:doc@hostname.com" MimeType="application/pdf" />
    </LayoutElement>
    <LayoutPreparationParams ID="ProcessID_0" Class="Parameter" Status="Available" Rotate="Rotate0" PartIDKeys="RunIndex">
      <PageCell>
    <ImageShift PositionX="Center" PositionY="Center" />
      </PageCell>      
      <LayoutPreparationParams Sides="TwoSidedFlipY" RunIndex="0 1 3 4 6 7 9 10 12 13 15 16 18 19" />
      <LayoutPreparationParams Sides="OneSidedFront" RunIndex="2 5 8 11 14 17 20" />
    </LayoutPreparationParams>
    <InterpretingParams ID="ProcessID_2" Class="Parameter" Status="Available" />
    <RenderingParams ID="ProcessID_3" Class="Parameter" Status="Available" />
    <DigitalPrintingParams ID="ProcessID_4" Class="Parameter" Status="Available" PartIDKeys="RunIndex" Collate="Sheet" OutputBin="LargeCapacity-1">
      <Disjointing OffsetDirection="Alternate" />
      <DigitalPrintingParams RunIndex="0 1 3 4 6 7 9 10 12 13 15 16 18 19">
    <MediaRef rRef="media_0_size_from_catalog" />
      </DigitalPrintingParams>
      <DigitalPrintingParams RunIndex="2 5 8 11 14 17 20">
    <MediaRef rRef="media_1_size_from_catalog" />
      </DigitalPrintingParams>
    </DigitalPrintingParams>
    <Component ID="Product_4" Class="Quantity" Status="Unavailable" ComponentType="PartialProduct" />
    <HoleMakingParams ID="ProcessID_5" Class="Parameter" Status="Available" NoOp="true" />
    <Component ID="Product_5" Class="Quantity" Status="Unavailable" ComponentType="PartialProduct" />
    <FoldingParams ID="ProcessID_6" Class="Parameter" Status="Available" NoOp="true" />
    <Component ID="Product_6" Class="Quantity" Status="Unavailable" ComponentType="PartialProduct" />
    <StitchingParams ID="ProcessID_7" Class="Parameter" Status="Available" StitchType="Side" NumberOfStitches="0" />
    <Component ID="Product_7" Class="Quantity" Status="Unavailable" ComponentType="PartialProduct" />
    <Component ID="Product_Final" Class="Quantity" Status="Unavailable" ComponentType="FinalProduct" />
    <Media ID="media_0_size_from_catalog" Class="Consumable" Status="Available" DescriptiveName="LHINVE" oce:CustomMediaType="LHINVE" MediaColorNameDetails="White" Weight="75" HoleType="None" MediaSetCount="1" />
    <Media ID="media_1_size_from_catalog" Class="Consumable" Status="Available" DescriptiveName="Letter 8.5x11" oce:CustomMediaType="Letter 8.5x11" MediaColorNameDetails="White" Weight="70" HoleType="None" MediaSetCount="1" />
    <Contact ID="contact_1" Class="Parameter" Status="Available" ContactTypes="Owner Delivery" oce:UserID="PdfMergerTask        ">
      <oce:ComChannel ChannelType="ComputerName" Locator="MACH0010" />
    </Contact>
  </ResourcePool>
  <ResourceLinkPool>
    <CustomerInfoLink rRef="info_1" Usage="Input" />
    <RunListLink rRef="runlist_id" Usage="Input" />
    <MediaLink rRef="media_0_size_from_catalog" Usage="Input" />
    <MediaLink rRef="media_1_size_from_catalog" Usage="Input" />
    <LayoutPreparationParamsLink rRef="ProcessID_0" Usage="Input" />
    <InterpretingParamsLink rRef="ProcessID_2" Usage="Input" />
    <RenderingParamsLink rRef="ProcessID_3" Usage="Input" />
    <DigitalPrintingParamsLink rRef="ProcessID_4" Usage="Input" />
    <HoleMakingParamsLink rRef="ProcessID_5" Usage="Input" />
    <FoldingParamsLink rRef="ProcessID_6" Usage="Input" />
    <StitchingParamsLink rRef="ProcessID_7" Usage="Input" />
    <ComponentLink rRef="Product_Final" Usage="Output" Amount="1" />
  </ResourceLinkPool>
  <AuditPool>
    <Created ID="audit_1" AgentName="Oce VarioPrint 6250 PS US" AgentVersion="12,20,54,18 manjunathbs@MANJU-WIN7" TimeStamp="2014-10-23T19:20:42Z" />
  </AuditPool>
</JDF>
```

This doesn't:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<JDF ID="jdf_1" Type="Combined" Category="DigitalPrinting" Types="LayoutPreparation Imposition Interpreting Rendering DigitalPrinting HoleMaking Folding Stitching" Activation="Active" Status="Waiting" Version="1.3" xmlns="http://www.CIP4.org/JDFSchema_1_1" xmlns:oce="http://www.oce.com/JDF_Extension/1_00" DescriptiveName="test smaller batch">
  <Comment Name="oce:TicketVersion">4.00</Comment>
  <ResourcePool>
    <CustomerInfo ID="info_1" Class="Parameter" Status="Available" CustomerJobName="test smaller batch">
      <ContactRef rRef="contact_1" />
    </CustomerInfo>
    <RunList ID="runlist_id" Class="Parameter" Status="Available">
      <LayoutElementRef rRef="file_1" />
    </RunList>
    <LayoutElement ID="file_1" Class="Parameter" Status="Available">
      <FileSpec URL="cid:doc@hostname.com" MimeType="application/pdf" />
    </LayoutElement>
    <LayoutPreparationParams ID="ProcessID_0" Class="Parameter" Status="Available" Rotate="Rotate0" PartIDKeys="RunIndex">
      <PageCell>
    <ImageShift PositionX="Center" PositionY="Center" />
      </PageCell>      
      <LayoutPreparationParams Sides="TwoSidedFlipY" RunIndex="0 1 3 4 6 7 9 10 12 13 15 16 18 19 21 22 24 25 27 28 30 31 33 34 36 37 39 40 42 43 45 46 48 49 51 52 54 55 57 58 60 61 63 64 66 67 69 70 72 73 75 76 78 79 81 82 84 85 87 88 90 91 93 94 96 97 99 100 102 103 105 106 108 109 111 112 114 115 117 118 120 121 123 124 126 127 129 130 132 133 135 136 138 139 141 142 144 145 147 148 150 151 153 154 156 157 159 160 162 163 165 166 168 169 171 172 174 175 177 178 180 181 183 184 186 187 189 190 192 193 195 196 198 199 201 202 204 205 207 208 210 211 213 214 216 217 219 220 222 223 225 226 228 229 231 232 234 235 237 238 240 241 243 244 246 247 249 250 252 253 255 256 258 259 261 262 264 265 267 268 270 271 273 274 276 277 279 280 282 283 285 286 288 289 291 292 294 295 297 298 300 301 303 304 306 307 309 310 312 313 315 316 318 319 321 322 324 325 327 328 330 331 333 334 336 337 339 340 342 343 345 346 348 349 351 352 354 355 357 358 360 361 363 364 366 367 369 370 372 373 375 376 378 379 381 382 384 385 387 388 390 391 393 394 396 397 399 400 402 403 405 406 408 409 411 412 414 415 417 418 420 421 423 424 426 427 429 430 432 433 435 436 438 439 441 442 444 445 447 448 450 451 453 454 456 457 459 460 462 463 465 466 468 469 471 472 474 475 477 478 480 481 483 484 486 487 489 490 492 493 495 496 498 499 501 502 504 505 507 508 510 511 513 514 516 517 519 520 522 523 525 526 528 529 531 532 534 535 537 538 540 541 543 544 546 547 549 550 552 553 555 556 558 559 561 562 564 565 567 568 570 571 573 574 576 577 579 580 582 583 585 586 588 589 591 592 594 595 597 598 600 601 603 604 606 607 609 610 612 613 615 616 618 619 621 622 624 625 627 628 630 631 633 634 636 637 639 640 642 643 645 646 648 649 651 652 654 655 657 658 660 661 663 664 666 667 669 670 672 673 675 676 678 679 681 682 684 685 687 688 690 691 693 694 696 697 699 700 702 703 705 706 708 709 711 712 714 715 717 718 720 721 723 724 726 727 729 730 732 733 735 736 738 739 741 742 744 745 747 748 750 751 753 754 756 757 759 760 762 763 765 766 768 769 771 772 774 775 777 778 780 781 783 784 786 787 789 790 792 793 795 796 798 799 801 802 804 805 807 808 810 811 813 814 816 817 819 820 822 823 825 826 828 829 831 832 834 835 837 838 840 841 843 844 846 847 849 850 852 853 855 856 858 859 861 862 864 865 867 868 870 871 873 874 876 877 879 880 882 883 885 886 888 889 891 892 894 895 897 898 900 901 903 904 906 907 909 910 912 913 915 916 918 919 921 922 924 925 927 928 930 931 933 934 936 937 939 940 942 943 945 946 948 949 951 952 954 955 957 958 960 961 963 964 966 967 969 970 972 973 975 976 978 979 981 982 984 985 987 988 990 991 993 994 996 997 999 1000 1002 1003 1005 1006 1008 1009 1011 1012 1014 1015 1017 1018 1020 1021 1023 1024 1026 1027 1029 1030 1032 1033 1035 1036 1038 1039 1041 1042 1044 1045 1047 1048 1050 1051 1053 1054 1056 1057 1059 1060 1062 1063 1065 1066 1068 1069 1071 1072 1074 1075 1077 1078 1080 1081 1083 1084 1086 1087 1089 1090 1092 1093 1095 1096 1098 1099 1101 1102 1104 1105 1107 1108 1110 1111 1113 1114 1116 1117 1119 1120 1122 1123 1125 1126 1128 1129 1131 1132 1134 1135 1137 1138 1140 1141 1143 1144 1146 1147 1149 1150 1152 1153 1155 1156 1158 1159 1161 1162 1164 1165 1167 1168 1170 1171 1173 1174 1176 1177 1179 1180 1182 1183 1185 1186 1188 1189 1191 1192 1194 1195 1197 1198 1200 1201 1203 1204 1206 1207 1209 1210 1212 1213 1215 1216 1218 1219 1221 1222 1224 1225 1227 1228 1230 1231 1233 1234 1236 1237 1239 1240 1242 1243 1245 1246 1248 1249 1251 1252 1254 1255 1257 1258 1260 1261 1263 1264 1266 1267 1269 1270 1272 1273 1275 1276 1278 1279 1281 1282 1284 1285 1287 1288 1290 1291 1293 1294 1296 1297 1299 1300 1302 1303 1305 1306 1308 1309 1311 1312 1314 1315 1317 1318 1320 1321 1323 1324 1326 1327 1329 1330 1332 1333 1335 1336 1338 1339 1341 1342 1344 1345 1347 1348 1350 1351 1353 1354 1356 1357 1359 1360 1362 1363 1365 1366 1368 1369 1371 1372 1374 1375 1377 1378 1380 1381 1383 1384 1386 1387 1389 1390 1392 1393 1395 1396 1398 1399 1401 1402 1404 1405 1407 1408 1410 1411 1413 1414 1416 1417 1419 1420 1422 1423 1425 1426 1428 1429 1431 1432 1434 1435 1437 1438 1440 1441 1443 1444 1446 1447 1449 1450 1452 1453 1455 1456 1458 1459 1461 1462 1464 1465 1467 1468 1470 1471 1473 1474 1476 1477 1479 1480 1482 1483 1485 1486 1488 1489 1491 1492 1494 1495 1497 1498 1500 1501 1503 1504 1506 1507 1509 1510 1512 1513 1515 1516 1518 1519 1521 1522 1524 1525 1527 1528 1530 1531 1533 1534 1536 1537 1539 1540 1542 1543 1545 1546 1548 1549 1551 1552 1554 1555 1557 1558 1560 1561 1563 1564 1566 1567 1569 1570 1572 1573 1575 1576 1578 1579 1581 1582 1584 1585 1587 1588 1590 1591 1593 1594 1596 1597 1599 1600 1602 1603 1605 1606 1608 1609 1611 1612 1614 1615 1617 1618 1620 1621 1623 1624 1626 1627 1629 1630 1632 1633 1635 1636 1638 1639 1641 1642 1644 1645 1647 1648 1650 1651 1653 1654 1656 1657 1659 1660 1662 1663 1665 1666 1668 1669 1671 1672 1674 1675 1677 1678 1680 1681 1683 1684 1686 1687 1689 1690 1692 1693 1695 1696 1698 1699 1701 1702 1704 1705 1707 1708 1710 1711 1713 1714 1716 1717 1719 1720 1722 1723 1725 1726 1728 1729 1731 1732 1734 1735 1737 1738 1740 1741 1743 1744 1746 1747 1749 1750 1752 1753 1755 1756 1758 1759 1761 1762 1764 1765 1767 1768 1770 1771 1773 1774 1776 1777 1779 1780 1782 1783 1785 1786 1788 1789 1791 1792 1794 1795 1797 1798 1800 1801 1803 1804 1806 1807 1809 1810 1812 1813 1815 1816 1818 1819 1821 1822 1824 1825 1827 1828 1830 1831 1833 1834 1836 1837 1839 1840 1842 1843 1845 1846 1848 1849 1851 1852 1854 1855 1857 1858 1860 1861 1863 1864 1866 1867 1869 1870 1872 1873 1875 1876 1878 1879 1881 1882 1884 1885 1887 1888 1890 1891 1893 1894 1896 1897 1899 1900 1902 1903 1905 1906 1908 1909 1911 1912 1914 1915 1917 1918 1920 1921 1923 1924 1926 1927 1929 1930 1932 1933 1935 1936 1938 1939 1941 1942 1944 1945 1947 1948 1950 1951 1953 1954 1956 1957 1959 1960 1962 1963 1965 1966 1968 1969 1971 1972 1974 1975 1977 1978 1980 1981 1983 1984 1986 1987 1989 1990 1992 1993 1995 1996 1998 1999 2001 2002 2004 2005 2007 2008 2010 2011 2013 2014 2016 2017 2019 2020 2022 2023 2025 2026 2028 2029 2031 2032 2034 2035 2037 2038 2040 2041 2043 2044 2046 2047 2049 2050 2052 2053 2055 2056 2058 2059 2061 2062 2064 2065 2067 2068 2070 2071 2073 2074 2076 2077 2079 2080 2082 2083 2085 2086 2088 2089 2091 2092 2094 2095 2097 2098" />
      <LayoutPreparationParams Sides="OneSidedFront" RunIndex="2 5 8 11 14 17 20 23 26 29 32 35 38 41 44 47 50 53 56 59 62 65 68 71 74 77 80 83 86 89 92 95 98 101 104 107 110 113 116 119 122 125 128 131 134 137 140 143 146 149 152 155 158 161 164 167 170 173 176 179 182 185 188 191 194 197 200 203 206 209 212 215 218 221 224 227 230 233 236 239 242 245 248 251 254 257 260 263 266 269 272 275 278 281 284 287 290 293 296 299 302 305 308 311 314 317 320 323 326 329 332 335 338 341 344 347 350 353 356 359 362 365 368 371 374 377 380 383 386 389 392 395 398 401 404 407 410 413 416 419 422 425 428 431 434 437 440 443 446 449 452 455 458 461 464 467 470 473 476 479 482 485 488 491 494 497 500 503 506 509 512 515 518 521 524 527 530 533 536 539 542 545 548 551 554 557 560 563 566 569 572 575 578 581 584 587 590 593 596 599 602 605 608 611 614 617 620 623 626 629 632 635 638 641 644 647 650 653 656 659 662 665 668 671 674 677 680 683 686 689 692 695 698 701 704 707 710 713 716 719 722 725 728 731 734 737 740 743 746 749 752 755 758 761 764 767 770 773 776 779 782 785 788 791 794 797 800 803 806 809 812 815 818 821 824 827 830 833 836 839 842 845 848 851 854 857 860 863 866 869 872 875 878 881 884 887 890 893 896 899 902 905 908 911 914 917 920 923 926 929 932 935 938 941 944 947 950 953 956 959 962 965 968 971 974 977 980 983 986 989 992 995 998 1001 1004 1007 1010 1013 1016 1019 1022 1025 1028 1031 1034 1037 1040 1043 1046 1049 1052 1055 1058 1061 1064 1067 1070 1073 1076 1079 1082 1085 1088 1091 1094 1097 1100 1103 1106 1109 1112 1115 1118 1121 1124 1127 1130 1133 1136 1139 1142 1145 1148 1151 1154 1157 1160 1163 1166 1169 1172 1175 1178 1181 1184 1187 1190 1193 1196 1199 1202 1205 1208 1211 1214 1217 1220 1223 1226 1229 1232 1235 1238 1241 1244 1247 1250 1253 1256 1259 1262 1265 1268 1271 1274 1277 1280 1283 1286 1289 1292 1295 1298 1301 1304 1307 1310 1313 1316 1319 1322 1325 1328 1331 1334 1337 1340 1343 1346 1349 1352 1355 1358 1361 1364 1367 1370 1373 1376 1379 1382 1385 1388 1391 1394 1397 1400 1403 1406 1409 1412 1415 1418 1421 1424 1427 1430 1433 1436 1439 1442 1445 1448 1451 1454 1457 1460 1463 1466 1469 1472 1475 1478 1481 1484 1487 1490 1493 1496 1499 1502 1505 1508 1511 1514 1517 1520 1523 1526 1529 1532 1535 1538 1541 1544 1547 1550 1553 1556 1559 1562 1565 1568 1571 1574 1577 1580 1583 1586 1589 1592 1595 1598 1601 1604 1607 1610 1613 1616 1619 1622 1625 1628 1631 1634 1637 1640 1643 1646 1649 1652 1655 1658 1661 1664 1667 1670 1673 1676 1679 1682 1685 1688 1691 1694 1697 1700 1703 1706 1709 1712 1715 1718 1721 1724 1727 1730 1733 1736 1739 1742 1745 1748 1751 1754 1757 1760 1763 1766 1769 1772 1775 1778 1781 1784 1787 1790 1793 1796 1799 1802 1805 1808 1811 1814 1817 1820 1823 1826 1829 1832 1835 1838 1841 1844 1847 1850 1853 1856 1859 1862 1865 1868 1871 1874 1877 1880 1883 1886 1889 1892 1895 1898 1901 1904 1907 1910 1913 1916 1919 1922 1925 1928 1931 1934 1937 1940 1943 1946 1949 1952 1955 1958 1961 1964 1967 1970 1973 1976 1979 1982 1985 1988 1991 1994 1997 2000 2003 2006 2009 2012 2015 2018 2021 2024 2027 2030 2033 2036 2039 2042 2045 2048 2051 2054 2057 2060 2063 2066 2069 2072 2075 2078 2081 2084 2087 2090 2093 2096 2099" />
    </LayoutPreparationParams>
    <InterpretingParams ID="ProcessID_2" Class="Parameter" Status="Available" />
    <RenderingParams ID="ProcessID_3" Class="Parameter" Status="Available" />
    <DigitalPrintingParams ID="ProcessID_4" Class="Parameter" Status="Available" PartIDKeys="RunIndex" Collate="Sheet" OutputBin="LargeCapacity-1">
      <Disjointing OffsetDirection="Alternate" />
      <DigitalPrintingParams RunIndex="0 1 3 4 6 7 9 10 12 13 15 16 18 19 21 22 24 25 27 28 30 31 33 34 36 37 39 40 42 43 45 46 48 49 51 52 54 55 57 58 60 61 63 64 66 67 69 70 72 73 75 76 78 79 81 82 84 85 87 88 90 91 93 94 96 97 99 100 102 103 105 106 108 109 111 112 114 115 117 118 120 121 123 124 126 127 129 130 132 133 135 136 138 139 141 142 144 145 147 148 150 151 153 154 156 157 159 160 162 163 165 166 168 169 171 172 174 175 177 178 180 181 183 184 186 187 189 190 192 193 195 196 198 199 201 202 204 205 207 208 210 211 213 214 216 217 219 220 222 223 225 226 228 229 231 232 234 235 237 238 240 241 243 244 246 247 249 250 252 253 255 256 258 259 261 262 264 265 267 268 270 271 273 274 276 277 279 280 282 283 285 286 288 289 291 292 294 295 297 298 300 301 303 304 306 307 309 310 312 313 315 316 318 319 321 322 324 325 327 328 330 331 333 334 336 337 339 340 342 343 345 346 348 349 351 352 354 355 357 358 360 361 363 364 366 367 369 370 372 373 375 376 378 379 381 382 384 385 387 388 390 391 393 394 396 397 399 400 402 403 405 406 408 409 411 412 414 415 417 418 420 421 423 424 426 427 429 430 432 433 435 436 438 439 441 442 444 445 447 448 450 451 453 454 456 457 459 460 462 463 465 466 468 469 471 472 474 475 477 478 480 481 483 484 486 487 489 490 492 493 495 496 498 499 501 502 504 505 507 508 510 511 513 514 516 517 519 520 522 523 525 526 528 529 531 532 534 535 537 538 540 541 543 544 546 547 549 550 552 553 555 556 558 559 561 562 564 565 567 568 570 571 573 574 576 577 579 580 582 583 585 586 588 589 591 592 594 595 597 598 600 601 603 604 606 607 609 610 612 613 615 616 618 619 621 622 624 625 627 628 630 631 633 634 636 637 639 640 642 643 645 646 648 649 651 652 654 655 657 658 660 661 663 664 666 667 669 670 672 673 675 676 678 679 681 682 684 685 687 688 690 691 693 694 696 697 699 700 702 703 705 706 708 709 711 712 714 715 717 718 720 721 723 724 726 727 729 730 732 733 735 736 738 739 741 742 744 745 747 748 750 751 753 754 756 757 759 760 762 763 765 766 768 769 771 772 774 775 777 778 780 781 783 784 786 787 789 790 792 793 795 796 798 799 801 802 804 805 807 808 810 811 813 814 816 817 819 820 822 823 825 826 828 829 831 832 834 835 837 838 840 841 843 844 846 847 849 850 852 853 855 856 858 859 861 862 864 865 867 868 870 871 873 874 876 877 879 880 882 883 885 886 888 889 891 892 894 895 897 898 900 901 903 904 906 907 909 910 912 913 915 916 918 919 921 922 924 925 927 928 930 931 933 934 936 937 939 940 942 943 945 946 948 949 951 952 954 955 957 958 960 961 963 964 966 967 969 970 972 973 975 976 978 979 981 982 984 985 987 988 990 991 993 994 996 997 999 1000 1002 1003 1005 1006 1008 1009 1011 1012 1014 1015 1017 1018 1020 1021 1023 1024 1026 1027 1029 1030 1032 1033 1035 1036 1038 1039 1041 1042 1044 1045 1047 1048 1050 1051 1053 1054 1056 1057 1059 1060 1062 1063 1065 1066 1068 1069 1071 1072 1074 1075 1077 1078 1080 1081 1083 1084 1086 1087 1089 1090 1092 1093 1095 1096 1098 1099 1101 1102 1104 1105 1107 1108 1110 1111 1113 1114 1116 1117 1119 1120 1122 1123 1125 1126 1128 1129 1131 1132 1134 1135 1137 1138 1140 1141 1143 1144 1146 1147 1149 1150 1152 1153 1155 1156 1158 1159 1161 1162 1164 1165 1167 1168 1170 1171 1173 1174 1176 1177 1179 1180 1182 1183 1185 1186 1188 1189 1191 1192 1194 1195 1197 1198 1200 1201 1203 1204 1206 1207 1209 1210 1212 1213 1215 1216 1218 1219 1221 1222 1224 1225 1227 1228 1230 1231 1233 1234 1236 1237 1239 1240 1242 1243 1245 1246 1248 1249 1251 1252 1254 1255 1257 1258 1260 1261 1263 1264 1266 1267 1269 1270 1272 1273 1275 1276 1278 1279 1281 1282 1284 1285 1287 1288 1290 1291 1293 1294 1296 1297 1299 1300 1302 1303 1305 1306 1308 1309 1311 1312 1314 1315 1317 1318 1320 1321 1323 1324 1326 1327 1329 1330 1332 1333 1335 1336 1338 1339 1341 1342 1344 1345 1347 1348 1350 1351 1353 1354 1356 1357 1359 1360 1362 1363 1365 1366 1368 1369 1371 1372 1374 1375 1377 1378 1380 1381 1383 1384 1386 1387 1389 1390 1392 1393 1395 1396 1398 1399 1401 1402 1404 1405 1407 1408 1410 1411 1413 1414 1416 1417 1419 1420 1422 1423 1425 1426 1428 1429 1431 1432 1434 1435 1437 1438 1440 1441 1443 1444 1446 1447 1449 1450 1452 1453 1455 1456 1458 1459 1461 1462 1464 1465 1467 1468 1470 1471 1473 1474 1476 1477 1479 1480 1482 1483 1485 1486 1488 1489 1491 1492 1494 1495 1497 1498 1500 1501 1503 1504 1506 1507 1509 1510 1512 1513 1515 1516 1518 1519 1521 1522 1524 1525 1527 1528 1530 1531 1533 1534 1536 1537 1539 1540 1542 1543 1545 1546 1548 1549 1551 1552 1554 1555 1557 1558 1560 1561 1563 1564 1566 1567 1569 1570 1572 1573 1575 1576 1578 1579 1581 1582 1584 1585 1587 1588 1590 1591 1593 1594 1596 1597 1599 1600 1602 1603 1605 1606 1608 1609 1611 1612 1614 1615 1617 1618 1620 1621 1623 1624 1626 1627 1629 1630 1632 1633 1635 1636 1638 1639 1641 1642 1644 1645 1647 1648 1650 1651 1653 1654 1656 1657 1659 1660 1662 1663 1665 1666 1668 1669 1671 1672 1674 1675 1677 1678 1680 1681 1683 1684 1686 1687 1689 1690 1692 1693 1695 1696 1698 1699 1701 1702 1704 1705 1707 1708 1710 1711 1713 1714 1716 1717 1719 1720 1722 1723 1725 1726 1728 1729 1731 1732 1734 1735 1737 1738 1740 1741 1743 1744 1746 1747 1749 1750 1752 1753 1755 1756 1758 1759 1761 1762 1764 1765 1767 1768 1770 1771 1773 1774 1776 1777 1779 1780 1782 1783 1785 1786 1788 1789 1791 1792 1794 1795 1797 1798 1800 1801 1803 1804 1806 1807 1809 1810 1812 1813 1815 1816 1818 1819 1821 1822 1824 1825 1827 1828 1830 1831 1833 1834 1836 1837 1839 1840 1842 1843 1845 1846 1848 1849 1851 1852 1854 1855 1857 1858 1860 1861 1863 1864 1866 1867 1869 1870 1872 1873 1875 1876 1878 1879 1881 1882 1884 1885 1887 1888 1890 1891 1893 1894 1896 1897 1899 1900 1902 1903 1905 1906 1908 1909 1911 1912 1914 1915 1917 1918 1920 1921 1923 1924 1926 1927 1929 1930 1932 1933 1935 1936 1938 1939 1941 1942 1944 1945 1947 1948 1950 1951 1953 1954 1956 1957 1959 1960 1962 1963 1965 1966 1968 1969 1971 1972 1974 1975 1977 1978 1980 1981 1983 1984 1986 1987 1989 1990 1992 1993 1995 1996 1998 1999 2001 2002 2004 2005 2007 2008 2010 2011 2013 2014 2016 2017 2019 2020 2022 2023 2025 2026 2028 2029 2031 2032 2034 2035 2037 2038 2040 2041 2043 2044 2046 2047 2049 2050 2052 2053 2055 2056 2058 2059 2061 2062 2064 2065 2067 2068 2070 2071 2073 2074 2076 2077 2079 2080 2082 2083 2085 2086 2088 2089 2091 2092 2094 2095 2097 2098">
    <MediaRef rRef="media_0_size_from_catalog" />
      </DigitalPrintingParams>
      <DigitalPrintingParams RunIndex="2 5 8 11 14 17 20 23 26 29 32 35 38 41 44 47 50 53 56 59 62 65 68 71 74 77 80 83 86 89 92 95 98 101 104 107 110 113 116 119 122 125 128 131 134 137 140 143 146 149 152 155 158 161 164 167 170 173 176 179 182 185 188 191 194 197 200 203 206 209 212 215 218 221 224 227 230 233 236 239 242 245 248 251 254 257 260 263 266 269 272 275 278 281 284 287 290 293 296 299 302 305 308 311 314 317 320 323 326 329 332 335 338 341 344 347 350 353 356 359 362 365 368 371 374 377 380 383 386 389 392 395 398 401 404 407 410 413 416 419 422 425 428 431 434 437 440 443 446 449 452 455 458 461 464 467 470 473 476 479 482 485 488 491 494 497 500 503 506 509 512 515 518 521 524 527 530 533 536 539 542 545 548 551 554 557 560 563 566 569 572 575 578 581 584 587 590 593 596 599 602 605 608 611 614 617 620 623 626 629 632 635 638 641 644 647 650 653 656 659 662 665 668 671 674 677 680 683 686 689 692 695 698 701 704 707 710 713 716 719 722 725 728 731 734 737 740 743 746 749 752 755 758 761 764 767 770 773 776 779 782 785 788 791 794 797 800 803 806 809 812 815 818 821 824 827 830 833 836 839 842 845 848 851 854 857 860 863 866 869 872 875 878 881 884 887 890 893 896 899 902 905 908 911 914 917 920 923 926 929 932 935 938 941 944 947 950 953 956 959 962 965 968 971 974 977 980 983 986 989 992 995 998 1001 1004 1007 1010 1013 1016 1019 1022 1025 1028 1031 1034 1037 1040 1043 1046 1049 1052 1055 1058 1061 1064 1067 1070 1073 1076 1079 1082 1085 1088 1091 1094 1097 1100 1103 1106 1109 1112 1115 1118 1121 1124 1127 1130 1133 1136 1139 1142 1145 1148 1151 1154 1157 1160 1163 1166 1169 1172 1175 1178 1181 1184 1187 1190 1193 1196 1199 1202 1205 1208 1211 1214 1217 1220 1223 1226 1229 1232 1235 1238 1241 1244 1247 1250 1253 1256 1259 1262 1265 1268 1271 1274 1277 1280 1283 1286 1289 1292 1295 1298 1301 1304 1307 1310 1313 1316 1319 1322 1325 1328 1331 1334 1337 1340 1343 1346 1349 1352 1355 1358 1361 1364 1367 1370 1373 1376 1379 1382 1385 1388 1391 1394 1397 1400 1403 1406 1409 1412 1415 1418 1421 1424 1427 1430 1433 1436 1439 1442 1445 1448 1451 1454 1457 1460 1463 1466 1469 1472 1475 1478 1481 1484 1487 1490 1493 1496 1499 1502 1505 1508 1511 1514 1517 1520 1523 1526 1529 1532 1535 1538 1541 1544 1547 1550 1553 1556 1559 1562 1565 1568 1571 1574 1577 1580 1583 1586 1589 1592 1595 1598 1601 1604 1607 1610 1613 1616 1619 1622 1625 1628 1631 1634 1637 1640 1643 1646 1649 1652 1655 1658 1661 1664 1667 1670 1673 1676 1679 1682 1685 1688 1691 1694 1697 1700 1703 1706 1709 1712 1715 1718 1721 1724 1727 1730 1733 1736 1739 1742 1745 1748 1751 1754 1757 1760 1763 1766 1769 1772 1775 1778 1781 1784 1787 1790 1793 1796 1799 1802 1805 1808 1811 1814 1817 1820 1823 1826 1829 1832 1835 1838 1841 1844 1847 1850 1853 1856 1859 1862 1865 1868 1871 1874 1877 1880 1883 1886 1889 1892 1895 1898 1901 1904 1907 1910 1913 1916 1919 1922 1925 1928 1931 1934 1937 1940 1943 1946 1949 1952 1955 1958 1961 1964 1967 1970 1973 1976 1979 1982 1985 1988 1991 1994 1997 2000 2003 2006 2009 2012 2015 2018 2021 2024 2027 2030 2033 2036 2039 2042 2045 2048 2051 2054 2057 2060 2063 2066 2069 2072 2075 2078 2081 2084 2087 2090 2093 2096 2099">
    <MediaRef rRef="media_1_size_from_catalog" />
      </DigitalPrintingParams>
    </DigitalPrintingParams>
    <Component ID="Product_4" Class="Quantity" Status="Unavailable" ComponentType="PartialProduct" />
    <HoleMakingParams ID="ProcessID_5" Class="Parameter" Status="Available" NoOp="true" />
    <Component ID="Product_5" Class="Quantity" Status="Unavailable" ComponentType="PartialProduct" />
    <FoldingParams ID="ProcessID_6" Class="Parameter" Status="Available" NoOp="true" />
    <Component ID="Product_6" Class="Quantity" Status="Unavailable" ComponentType="PartialProduct" />
    <StitchingParams ID="ProcessID_7" Class="Parameter" Status="Available" StitchType="Side" NumberOfStitches="0" />
    <Component ID="Product_7" Class="Quantity" Status="Unavailable" ComponentType="PartialProduct" />
    <Component ID="Product_Final" Class="Quantity" Status="Unavailable" ComponentType="FinalProduct" />
    <Media ID="media_0_size_from_catalog" Class="Consumable" Status="Available" DescriptiveName="LHINVE" oce:CustomMediaType="LHINVE" MediaColorNameDetails="White" Weight="75" HoleType="None" MediaSetCount="1" />
    <Media ID="media_1_size_from_catalog" Class="Consumable" Status="Available" DescriptiveName="Letter 8.5x11" oce:CustomMediaType="Letter 8.5x11" MediaColorNameDetails="White" Weight="70" HoleType="None" MediaSetCount="1" />
    <Contact ID="contact_1" Class="Parameter" Status="Available" ContactTypes="Owner Delivery" oce:UserID="PdfMergerTask        ">
      <oce:ComChannel ChannelType="ComputerName" Locator="MACH0010" />
    </Contact>
  </ResourcePool>
  <ResourceLinkPool>
    <CustomerInfoLink rRef="info_1" Usage="Input" />
    <RunListLink rRef="runlist_id" Usage="Input" />
    <MediaLink rRef="media_0_size_from_catalog" Usage="Input" />
    <MediaLink rRef="media_1_size_from_catalog" Usage="Input" />
    <LayoutPreparationParamsLink rRef="ProcessID_0" Usage="Input" />
    <InterpretingParamsLink rRef="ProcessID_2" Usage="Input" />
    <RenderingParamsLink rRef="ProcessID_3" Usage="Input" />
    <DigitalPrintingParamsLink rRef="ProcessID_4" Usage="Input" />
    <HoleMakingParamsLink rRef="ProcessID_5" Usage="Input" />
    <FoldingParamsLink rRef="ProcessID_6" Usage="Input" />
    <StitchingParamsLink rRef="ProcessID_7" Usage="Input" />
    <ComponentLink rRef="Product_Final" Usage="Output" Amount="1" />
  </ResourceLinkPool>
  <AuditPool>
    <Created ID="audit_1" AgentName="Oce VarioPrint 6250 PS US" AgentVersion="12,20,54,18 manjunathbs@MANJU-WIN7" TimeStamp="2014-10-23T19:20:42Z" />
  </AuditPool>
</JDF>
```

I tried splitting up the elements and using subsets of the RunIndex values, and it worked on the tiny job above going from the above to change the lines below:

```
  <LayoutPreparationParams Sides="TwoSidedFlipY" RunIndex="0 1 3 4 6 7 9 10" />
  <LayoutPreparationParams Sides="TwoSidedFlipY" RunIndex="12 13 15 16 18 19" />
  <LayoutPreparationParams Sides="OneSidedFront" RunIndex="2 5 8 11" />
  <LayoutPreparationParams Sides="OneSidedFront" RunIndex="14 17 20" />
```

and...

```
  <DigitalPrintingParams RunIndex="0 1 3 4 6 7 9 10">
    <MediaRef rRef="media_0_size_from_catalog" />
  </DigitalPrintingParams>
  <DigitalPrintingParams RunIndex="2 5 8 11">
    <MediaRef rRef="media_1_size_from_catalog" />
  </DigitalPrintingParams>
  <DigitalPrintingParams RunIndex="12 13 15 16 18 19">
    <MediaRef rRef="media_0_size_from_catalog" />
  </DigitalPrintingParams>
  <DigitalPrintingParams RunIndex="14 17 20">
    <MediaRef rRef="media_1_size_from_catalog" />
  </DigitalPrintingParams>
```

This printed correctly, so I tried doing the same with the large jdf data, but it still failed.

Edit: The PDF by itself loads in Acrobat.

Conclusions:
Kurt suggested I check the pdf. Basic debugging, but I had printed pdfs previously, so assumed this was not the issue. It turned out it was. The important clue was when Kurt suggested I use Acrobat -> Preflight to check the PDF. Found a missing XObject in the pdf.

Comment: Acrobat "loads" a lot of b0rken files, without even giving a warning! *(Sometimes, upon closing the file, it will ask: **"Do you want to save your changes?"**, even though you didn't change anything. This indicates that Acrobat itself had to silently correct something in order to open the file...) -- I didn't ask if Acrobat "loads" the file. I meant "validation" through its builtin "Preflight" module...

Comment: @KurtPfeifle: Your suggestion above to use the Preflight was helpful. Though Acrobat read the first page, Preflight found an error on page 937. When I scrolled to that page, Acrobat then reported the error, and the page was blank. I have a bunch of manipulation I did on these pages using a combination of iTextSharp and PdfSharp. I am masking images and text and adding a datamatrix bitmap. The pages are mostly identical. I cannot post them as they are business documents. I will share my results when I get a further along. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I found the problem. Totally separate from the JDF as Kurt below suspected. I will edit in the findings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error message clearly hints at the 1500 page PDF being the problem:

> *"Pdf conversion error: Expected a name object."*

### **If indeed the PDF causes the problem...**

Start debugging the PDF:

- Does it validate with Adobe Acrobat?
- Does it print successfully if you do not use a prepended JDF (or a much smaller, simpler JDF)?

If this does not dig out a problem, proceed with analysing the JDF.

### **If indeed the JDF/XML causes the problem...**

I saved your two JDFs as `1.jdf` and `2.jdf`.

Your second JDF file leads to parsing errors when I run:

```
xml-less 2.jdf
```

The message is: `parsing error at file offset 50c0: mismatched tag`. (The file offset in this message is given in hex, so in decimal that is 20672.)

Looking into the surrounding lines, I find these nested tags (starting after line 14):

```xml
         <LayoutPreparationParams>
             <PageCell>
                 <ImageShift>
                 </ImageShift>
             </PageCell>
             <LayoutPreparationParams>
             </LayoutPreparationParams>
             <LayoutPreparationParams>
             </LayoutPreparationParams>
         </LayoutPreparationParams>
```

So there is `<LayoutPreparationParams ...` nested within `<LayoutPreparationParams ...`. I'm not sure if that is how it ought to be?

Also, here are some more details (with line numbers):

```
23     <DigitalPrintingParams ... >
[...]
25     <DigitalPrintingParams ... >
[...]
27     </DigitalPrintingParams ... >
28     <DigitalPrintingParams ... >
[...]
30     </DigitalPrintingParams ... >
31     </DigitalPrintingParams ... >
```

When I run...

```
xml-fixtags 2.jdf
```

...I see this output:

```
xml-fixtags: warning: maximum cstring_t size reached! (req. 1052755329)
xml-fixtags: warning: maximum cstring_t size reached! (req. 1052755329)
xml-fixtags: warning: maximum cstring_t size reached! (req. 1052755329)
xml-fixtags: warning: maximum cstring_t size reached! (req. 1052755329)
xml-fixtags: warning: maximum cstring_t size reached! (req. 1052755329)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I should have clarified some of these things, so I will do so above. The Layout of the XML is the same for both files, and one works and the other doesn't. I believe that the tags are closed correctly, but that the strings are overflowing your validator's buffer, but I will double check

Comment: @RobbSadler: I checked some more... Both your JDF files are indeed identically strucured, and only the contents of the `RunIndex="..."` fields are different (plus the `CustomerJobName="..."` and `DescriptiveName="..."`).

Comment: Ok, I might be barking up the wrong tree. I incorrectly assumed that the PDF would print standalone, as we print PDFs with 1000's of pages here regularly. But when I sent it without the JDF prepended, the Oce printer still choked. I will have to dig more, and update when I have more information.

Comment: @RobbSadler: if you want to provide (a link to) the PDF in question, I may be able to debug (and possibly fix) it.

Comment: @KurtPfeile: Agreed. Done.